# xcopy как передать параметры на удаленную машину?

Tags: python

Никак не могу передать xcopy параметры, делает копию на локальной машине

```
def silent_install():
    subprocess.call("xcopy tightvnc-2.7.10-setup-64bit.msi \\%s\c$\TV\ /i" % name_pc)
    global vnc_pass
    vnc_pass = input("Введи пароль:")
    os.system("winrs -r:%s msiexec.exe /i C:\TV\tightvnc-2.7.10-setup-64bit.msi /quiet /norestart SET_USEVNCAUTHENTICATION=1 VALUE_OF_USEVNCAUTHENTICATION=1 SET_PASSWORD=1 VALUE_OF_PASSWORD=%s SET_VIEWONLYPASSWORD=1 VALUE_OF_VIEWONLYPASSWORD=%s SET_USECONTROLAUTHENTICATION=1 VALUE_OF_USECONTROLAUTHENTICATION=1 SET_CONTROLPASSWORD=1 VALUE_OF_CONTROLPASSWORD=%s" % (name_pc, vnc_pass, vnc_pass, vnc_pass))
```

Comment: Добавьте тексты команд с выполненными подстановками параметров. Чтобы нам не гадать...

Comment: subprocess.call("xcopy tightvnc-2.7.10-setup-64bit.msi \\kraz-wd-175323\c$\TV\ /i") без разницы даже если просто запустить. Как мы мне запустить xcopy с передачей параметров?

Comment: ЕМНИП символ обратного слэша - немножко экранирующий... его удвоить не надо? типа `subprocess.call("xcopy tightvnc-2.7.10-setup-64bit.msi \\\\%s\\c$\\TV\\ /i" % name_pc)`...

Comment: точно, заработало! Спасибо огромное.